# jquery dialog not opening/closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have code like this:

The dialog does not open when i use this.

```
 else if (json.score == -3) {
      $("#dialog-unauthenticated").dialog('open');
     }
```

but does when i use this! I have it initialized with autopen false above too.

```
else if (json.score == -3) {
                       $("#dialog-unauthenticated").dialog({
                            resizable: false,
                            height: 140,
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                "OK": function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
```

what is wrong?
close does not work either.

initialized with:

```
$("#dialog-unauthenticated").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "OK": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure if this helps, but im invoking this in response to a jquery post.

Comment: @raklos , are you seeing any errors in firebug??

Comment: no it seems to get to the line of code, and just continue, but the dialog does not show.

Comment: can you show us your earlier code please? It looks like it isn't initialised so the issue may be there

Comment: @lnrbob - editted accordingly.

Comment: @raklos are you sure of id , it is class or id ,

Comment: @gov - got it working now. i was using id, the problem however was that multiple dialogs with the same id were being created! fixed now. sorry everyone!

Comment: @raklos , thats great to hear ,

Comment: I ran upon the same problem.. But when the dialog(s) with the same id aren't open at the same time this shouldn't be a problem right?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initiate the dialog first.
then you can do actions after.

so e.g.

```
$('<div id="dialog" />')
    .dialog({
        modal:true,
        buttons:{
           cancel:function(){
               $(this).dialog('close');
           }
        }
     });//init dialog
$('#open').click(function (){
   $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
$('#close').click(function (){
   $('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

As you are trying to `open` the dialog when its not initiated. therefore the dialog does not exist so it cnt be opened